# ffdf objects with stream and ffbase

Tags: r, stream

I'm trying to perform clustering on a large dataset which I have stored as an `ffdf` object from package `ffbase`. According to documentation for `ffbase` (notes from the useR!2013 conference), package `stream` provides support for doing this.

I have had a look at the functions in `stream` but I cannot see how to set up an `ffdf` as a stream. The only function I can think might work, `DSD_Wrapper`, does not work. I guess I should be using `DSD_ReadStream` but I don't know how to get it working.

Here's an mwe:

```
library(ffbase)
library(stream)

ffmt <- as.ffdf(mtcars)
dsmt <- DSD_Wrapper(mtcars) #works fine
dsff <- DSD_Wrapper(ffmt)   #does not work
```

Investigating the structure reveals that it is quite a simple object, and I could recreate it manually, although the size of my actual data prevents this.

Comment: It works fine for me . I have this configuration `R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`

Comment: How to set up an ffdf stream is explained at http://bnosac.be/index.php/blog/26-massive-online-data-stream-mining-with-r. The function to set up the stream is put here https://gist.github.com/jwijffels/5239198 and is called DSD_FFDFstream.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't working since the `DSD_FFDFstream` is not in either of packages stream or ffbase. Will it be included in future? Until then I'll just have to source the gist.